# I cannot extract a tar.gz file

Tags: anaconda, tar

I want to run the package and do this tutorial (https://github.com/flatironinstitute/inferelator/blob/master/Tutorial.md). I typed everything in Anaconda prompt and reaching to tar -xzf inferelator_example_data.tar.gz, I get this error message:

tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'inferelator_example_data.tar.gz'

I am a basic user. I am not sure if I can open this file by another way or the file itself has problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You can navigate to the folder and use `openssl md5 inferelator_example_data.tar.gz` to show the md5sum of the file. It should be f77c05242cabeab20b0e6c0ca7cfc3d2 - if it isn't there was a problem during transfer. Just delete it and download it again.

Comment: Thanks. My problem's resolved now :) @cel